# Time to deallocate the [alloc] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [alloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloc) exists with about 180 questions, but it has no tag wiki, and is applied lots of different languages without much evidence of coherence.  Usually, it is some sort of memory allocation question, but that's about as much as can be said for it.  There are some top users who've answered several questions with the tag, but the patterns are typical of an non-useful tag.

I'm proposing that the tag be eliminated.  Many of the C-tagged questions could be revised to use [malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/malloc) instead.  The C++, Java, C#, Objective-C, Erlang, Fortran (…) questions can probably lose the tag without suffering.

If it shouldn't be eliminated, some language-neutral tag wiki should be devised for it, pointing out the per-language preferred alternatives.

Or, if it is an appropriate tag for some language (or set of languages — [Objective C seems to be one such language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353949/time-to-deallocate-the-alloc-tag?noredirect=1#comment498396_353949)), the tag wiki should identify those languages (not language-neutral after all) and the list of questions with the tag scrutinized and cleaned up so that the use of the tag matches the tag wiki.

(We could also have a discussion on whether all of [malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/malloc), [calloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calloc), [realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realloc), [free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free) should exist.  That's somewhat tangential to this question, though.
Looking at the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page and typing `alloc` in the search box shows a lot of vaguely related tags.)

Comment: `delete[] alloc`

Comment: Is "alloc" a keyword or standard library function in some language(s)? If so, I think it's a reasonable tag, just like [malloc] in C. If not, yes, I agree that it should go.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, [it's a fundamental method in Cocoa/ObjC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571958-alloc).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: if `alloc` is a keyword in Objective-C, then it would be appropriate to add a tag wiki that specifies that is the appropriate context to use it.  And there should be a cleanup of the questions using other languages.

Comment: Which would be a uphill battle since [people don't read excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575)

Comment: @Braiam — that's a problem with every tag. Still, if there's a tag wiki, then those who care and curate the tag have guidelines to work to. At the moment, no-one knows what it's for, which makes it hard to use properly because no-one knows what it signifies.